# Some commands inside unix script are not working

Tags: unix

I have invoke_test.sh with below code:

```
echo "invoke script started"
sh test1.sh >output1.log &
sh test2.sh > output2.log
echo "test 1 completed " >> output1.log
echo "test 2 completed " >> output2.log
```

test1.sh:

```
echo "running test1.sh"
sleep 5
echo "test1.sh completed"
```

test2.sh:

```
echo "running test2.sh"
    sleep 10
    echo "test2.sh completed"
```

So when I execute invoke_test.sh by
sh invoke_test.sh

iN output log files i can find eg output1.log

running test1.sh
test1.sh completed

but not able to get the below line which i am trying to direct to log from invoke_test.sh script
test 1 completed

The requirements here is to run 2 shell scripts parallely and once both the execution completes I want to execute these 2 lines
echo "test 1 completed " >> output1.log
echo "test 2 completed " >> output2.log

I am new learner in unix so will appreciate why this behaviour is happening in a simple way and how can I achieve the desired output

Comment: Don't name your script with a `.sh` suffix: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Comment: Are you allowing the script to run to completion?  When it terminates, the line "test 1 completed" should be in `output1.log`. What is the result of `sh invoke_test.sh; cat output1.log`?

Comment: You may want to simply add `wait` at the end of the script, and it looks like you've got some cut-n-paste error since `test2.sh` appears to be the same as `test1.sh`.  Does your `test2.sh` actually sleep for a different amount of time than the `test1.sh`?  Even if they are both sleeping 5, there's a race condition, but the "test 1 completed" should be in the file no matter how that race is resolved.

Comment: @Anirudh Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. Copy&paste the output and/or file contents you get and format it as code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to `wait` until all the background processes are done, use `wait`:

```
echo "invoke script started"
sh test1.sh > output1.log &
sh test2.sh > output2.log &
wait   # wait for both of the background jobs to complete
echo "test 1 completed " >> output1.log
echo "test 2 completed " >> output2.log
```